# Style checkbox on Contact Form 7 WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, checkbox, contacts, contact-form-7

I was just wondering if there was a way anybody could think of to style a checkbox that is generated in the popular Contact Form 7 plugin on WordPress?

It's difficult to try and get it to work using raw code because Contact Form 7 works in tags/shortcode.

I would just like an orange background on the box which changes colour with a tick when checked, so nothing too complex (I hope).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No code, no answers - what have you achived so far?

Comment: Thanks for your response.There is no code to display because the plugin 'Contact Form 7' auto generates the form from shortcode that the user implements in the back end of WordPress. 

Currently, I just have a standard Checkbox that looks different on all browsers.

I have asked the question in this manner because I'm sure I'm not the only person to have the query with Contact Form 7.

Comment: That is absolutely true - I'm using it on my website too - because it is good. But the way you have asked just implies that you have not made any attempts so far to solve this problem yourself hence you are waiting for someone to solve it for you. Read the rules of Stack Overflow, and you'll get it. Questions like this result in glass balls hovering with your hand over it, trying to guess it.

Comment: Ok, I did say in the description 'It's difficult to try and get it to work using raw code because Contact Form 7 works in tags/shortcode.'.. so what I mean by this is I have tried to put <input> and <label> tags inside the Contact Form 7 box in the back end along with the image replacement trick in css to change the checkbox to a rollover image but it just didn't work (blank space) and if it did work, Contact Form 7 wouldn't be able to capture the data the user inputs because it only recognises the shortcode. Was wondering if there was any JS or CSS i can use to replace the standard checkbox

Comment: Why didn't you post that code? What kind of mental trick should we use to guess this... you could save some HTML which is output by contact form 7, you could create a screenshot of your code - you could post an example. This way - you have written 2 comments - but no code so far. Leaving us with the glasball again.. come on...

Comment: Ok, I have just made a little headway but still struggling with one final issue. I need the label text to be on one line. The width is set to 28px which is causing the text to appear over more than one line but when i make the width 100% it affects the circle.

See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lzbms2r8/